# How to deploy rules from Drools Guvnor

Tags: rest, soap, drools, rule, drools-guvnor

I want to execute Drools rules via REST or SOAP.
I'm already using Drools Guvnor as facts, rules designer/repository. And it works just fine, but I haven't found any clear guidance on how to deploy these rules for execution.

I would be grateful if anyone points to tutorial.

Is it achievable without Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to execute Drools rules via REST or SOAP, look into Drools Server.

http://www.plugtree.com/drools-server-overview/

In this setup, your rules are actually executed on the remote server.

If you just want to use the built rule package from Guvnor in a standalone Java application, there is plenty of information in the Guvnor documentation that will show you how to use the URL where guvnor exposes your compiled package. See Chapter 9 for Knowledge Agent configuration.

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.CR5/drools-guvnor-docs/pdf/drools-wb-docs.pdf

Comment: This article describes v5.0 of drools. I have tried out 5.5 and 6.0 version so far and stopped on 5.5 because v6 actually lacks documentation. In 5.5 version one can create Service Config and download WAR file. The thing is it fails to deploy on my tomcat6, I was curious if there is any tutorial describing this process, because most articles show java coding which I would like to avoid.